# AngularJS Directive template not rendering

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simple directive that just displays some text for now:

```
app.directive("exampleText", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        template: '<div>hello!</div>'
    }

});
```

In my index.html I have this:

```
<div class="container" ng-app="customerPortalApp">
  <div ui-view></div>
  <exampleText></exampleText>
</div>
```

`exampleText` is outside my `ui-view` as thats to do with my routes and works correctly. But its my understanding the directive template should render as is. Have I missed something?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

With a directive named:

```
app.directive("exampleText", ...
```

HTML should be:

```
<example-text></example-text>
```

From [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-custom-directives_matching-directives):

> Angular normalizes an element's tag and attribute name to determine
>   which elements match which directives. We typically refer to
>   directives by their case-sensitive camelCase normalized name (e.g.
>   ngModel). However, since HTML is case-insensitive, we refer to
>   directives in the DOM by lower-case forms, typically using
>   dash-delimited attributes on DOM elements (e.g. ng-model).

Comment: just a word of note tho. example-text failed but exampletext worked. it also did not like the - is that normal?

Comment: Did you leave the directive name as "exampleText"? Then "example-text" should work in your html.

Answer (score 3):

As tasseKATT noted the directive name should stay as "exampleText"
and the html element should be `<example-text>`

I thought a demo may help
[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/klode/vNLeL/)

the template:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <sample-text></sample-text>
</div>
```

the directive:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.directive('sampleText', function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        template: '<div>Some sample text here.</div>'
    };
});
```